# webview is not loading from table view cell

Tags: iphone, xcode, webview, tableview

Im adding a custom cell. Whenever someone presses the add button, a alert view pops up and they add a name of a website. once pressed saved, it gets saved in the table view cell under whatever name they choose. Then once someone clicks that cell i want it to load with http:// in my web view. the only problem is that its not loading. What am I doing wrong?

This is my table view controller

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellTwo";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Index Selected,%d",indexPath.row);
    MainTwoViewController *View = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainTwo"];

    View.urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.%@",tableData];
    View.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
}        

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    //Only do the following action if the user hits the ok button
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSString *tapTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        if (!tableData) {
            tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        }
        [tableData insertObject:tapTextField atIndex:0];
        [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

and of course i put this in the mainTwo view controller so it loads the urlString.

```
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString]]];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I just identified your problem.

What you should do is put a tap gesture on the custom cell label first of all.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *openURLTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openURLTapped:)];

keypadDisableTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
keypadDisableTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

[cell.textLabel addGestureRecognizer:openURLTapGestureRecognizer];
```

Now, in this `openURLTapped`, you can pass the url and open it.

```
-(void)openURLTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap
{
    // your code here
}
```

It will definitely resolve your issue.

Comment: This will do nothing. Why would you add a tap gesture when `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is anyway called?

Comment: No, actually when you make a custom cell, to make things easier you should handle each event with separate gestures. This way you can handle your code in a better way and donot do anything in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: That is absolutely beside the point. The question is about a web view not loading. So "it will definitely **not** resolve your issue".

Comment: You should put conditions in `didSelect` method. otherwise it will not work. You should try doing the way I said. Your method clearly states you haven't written the conditions properly.

Comment: That is again beside the point. It is irrelevant if the configuration code is in a button handler, in a table view callback or a segue callback. Your solution introduces a whole list of new complexities.

Answer (score 0):

You instantiate a view controller but do not show it.

Use storyboard segues instead and configure the new view controller in `prepareForSegue`.

Also, check the following:
If you are using storyboard, most likely you do not have to create cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Also, simplify:
<strike>`[NSString stringWithFormat@"%", string];`</strike>
--> `string`

Finally, check the url that arrives at the new view controller before you load the request. Make sure sure the url is correct. Implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` methods to check for loading failures or unexpected return data.

Answer (score 0):

i think your this code

```
View.urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.%@",tableData];
```

should be like

```
View.urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.%@",[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

at your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, and it is also advisable that you use NSLog to check at which point you loose your data